# NuxtJS 3 (Vue): Page content not loading when accessing directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Wassup Guys,
I am currently working on an anime page.

However, I have NUXTJS3 as setup together with Tailwinds Css.

My problem is, that when someone is accessing the page directly, the content is not loading.

Getting redirected with ***< NuxtLink >*** works, check the screeshots below.

nuxt.config.js

```
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    build: {
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {},
                },
            },
        },
    },
    css: [
        "~/assets/css/tailwind.css",
        '~/assets/scss/main.scss'

    ],
    
})
```

[image: nuxtlink]
[image: directly]

Comment: I forgot to add scoped styles...

Comment: <style lang="scss" scoped>
#content,
body {
  visibility: hidden;
}
html {
  background: rgb(22 22 22) !important;
}
#loader {
  visibility: visible;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>

Comment: Does the previous comment solve your issue or you just forgot to edit your question?